# Java recursion and local variables

Tags: java, variables, recursion, methods

So in this following method, there are two integers, `base` and `n`.

When `powerN(base, n-1) * base` happens, what exactly happens?

Only the `base` gets multiplied, but there are two local variables inside the method, so why doesn't both `n-1` and `base` get multiplied by base since those are both part of the method?

(Sorry if this is a newbish question, but I can't seem to grasp this concept.)

```
public int powerN(int base, int n)
{
    if (n == 0) {
       return 1;
    } else {
       return (powerN(base, n-1) * base); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the order of operations for example values:

```
base = 3, n = 4
Is 4 == 0? No
powerN(3, 3) * 3
    base = 3, n = 3
    Is 3 == 0? No
powerN(3, 2) * 3 * 3
        base = 3, n = 2
        Is 2 == 0? No
powerN(3, 1) * 3 * 3 * 3
            base = 3, n = 1
            Is 1 == 0? No
powerN(3, 0) * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3
                base = 3, n = 0
                Is 0 >= 0? Yes, return 1.  // Base Case
1 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3
81
```

The `powerN(base, n - 1)` does get multiplied by `base`, but not until that recursive call returns.  The base case, the most deeply nested call, returns `1` first.  Then the multiplications occur, one at each recursive call, and the recursive calls return `3`, `9`, `27` in turn, and the original call returns `81`.

Answer (score 0):

Java is pass by value.  When you call powerN(), it doesn't reference the local variable, it makes a copy.  Consider this code:

```
public func( int x ) {
   x = x + 1;
}

public void test() {
   int x = 1;
   func( x );
   System.out.println( x ); // x = 1, not 2
}
```

The recursion makes it harder to see the real question.